# How to close another element when another element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display a menu when I click a link and if another menu is open close it before displaying the other menu. In other words like an accordion menu, but I only need one menu open at a time. So far everything I tried does not work. I don't know Jquery to well but I will post my code that I have so far.

HTML

```
    <nav id="cat">
        <ol>
            <li><a title="" href="#1">1;</a></li>
            <li><a title="" href="#2">2</a></li>
            <li><a title="" href="#3">3</a></li>
            <li><a title="" href="#4">4</a></li>
            <li><a title="" href="#5">5</a></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>


    <nav class="sub">
        <ol id="1">
            <li><a title="" href="">1a</a></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

    <nav class="sub">
        <ol id="2">
            <li><a title="" href="">2a</a></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

    <nav class="sub">
        <ol id="3">
            <li><a title="" href="">3a</a></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

    <nav class="sub">
        <ol id="4">
            <li><a title="" href="">4a</a></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

    <nav class="sub">
        <ol id="5">
            <li><a title="" href="">5a</a></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
```

JQuery

```
$('.sub').hide();
$('#cat > ol > li > a').click(function(){
    var hrefSuffix = $('a').attr('href').split('#')[1];
    $('.sub > ol').attr(hrefSuffix).slideDown('slow');
    $('.sub').find('ol[id=' + hrefSuffix ']').slideUp('slow');
});
```

Comment: that's what accordion is. Only one item is active at a time. Try with this https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Okay thanks for informing me I thought all menus had to be open lol.

Comment: @ski: if you have found your answer, then close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a classic accordion implementation, You can make some tweaks like below.

```js
var $subs = $('.sub');
$('#cat > ol > li > a').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href'),
    $target = $(href);
  $target.stop().slideToggle('slow');
  $subs.not($target).stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

```css
.sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="cat">
  <ol>
    <li><a title="" href="#1">1;</a></li>
    <li><a title="" href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a title="" href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a title="" href="#4">4</a></li>
    <li><a title="" href="#5">5</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>


<nav class="sub" id="1">
  <ol>
    <li><a title="" href="">1a</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<nav class="sub" id="2">
  <ol>
    <li><a title="" href="">2a</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<nav class="sub" id="3">
  <ol>
    <li><a title="" href="">3a</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<nav class="sub" id="4">
  <ol>
    <li><a title="" href="">4a</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<nav class="sub" id="5">
  <ol>
    <li><a title="" href="">5a</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

add class on opened menu item, then, when you open another item, find previous by added class, hide it and remove class.

```
$(.menu-item).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('opened')){
        return;
    }
    $('.opened').slideUp('slow').removeClass('opened');
    $this.slideDown('slow').addClass('opened');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the accordion needs to be like this

HTML:

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">First Item</a>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>First Item content goes here</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Seccond Item</a>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Seccond Item content goes here</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Third Item</a>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Third Item content goes here</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.accordion{padding:0px;margin:0px;list-style:none;}
.accordion li{margin-bottom:5px;}
.accordion a{padding:10px;background:#eaeaea;display:block;}
.accordion .panel{display:none;}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion a").on('click', function(){
        var $allPanel = $(".accordion .panel");
        var $currentPanel = $(this).next('.panel');
        if($currentPanel.is(":hidden")){
            $(this).next('.panel').slideDown('fast');
        }else{
            $(this).next('.panel').slideUp('fast');   
        }
        $allPanel.not($currentPanel).slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

Created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zmvpgv00/), hope this is what you needed.